# How to use PowerShell to generate username based on filename of first and last name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We have a list of JPG files with comma separated filenames based on employee names (ie: "Smith, John.jpg").  I'd like to create a copy of this file based on their username (ie: "jsmith.jpg").

So basically I think I need to search AD based on the last name and first name in the filename, find the SAMAccountName and then create a copy of the file with that name.

Can anyone help me sort this out?

EDIT:

Here's what I went with thanks to the assistance below:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Folder = "G:\Photos" # folder that contains the JPG files
$Files = get-childitem $Folder

foreach ($file in $files)
{
$CurrentFileName = $file.name
$SplitCurrent = $CurrentFileName.Split(", ")
$LastName = $SplitCurrent[0]
$FirstName = $SplitCurrent[2].Substring(0,$SplitCurrent[2].Length-4)
$UserName = Get-ADUser -Filter 'GivenName -eq $FirstName -and sn -eq $LastName' -properties SamAccountName | select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
$NewFileName = $UserName + ".jpg"

Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination "$Folder\$NewFileName"
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question (and [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822), if relevant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need to get anything from AD, as long as the file names of the JPG files match the username.

The Code:

```
$Folder = "C:\Test" # folder that contains the JPG files

$Files = get-childitem $Folder
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $CurrentFileName = $file.name
    $SplitCurrent = $CurrentFileName.Split(",")
    $LastName = $SplitCurrent[0]
    $FirstInitial = $SplitCurrent[1].Substring(0,1)
    $NewFileName = $LastName + $FirstInitial + ".jpg"

    Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination "$Folder\$NewFileName"
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I used this and made some changes and it seems to do what I want, see my edit on the question